# Different options to move synapse workspace across different environments

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines, azure-synapse, azure-bicep

What are the different options to export a workspace let's say from Development into another workspace in TEST, UAT OR Production Synapse Analytics. Most of the options I have come across has been around copying code and pasting it in the intended environment. But, I want it to be automated so there's less moving parts and seamlessly move pipelines, linked services & datasets into different environments and less prone to run into errors.

[image]

Comment: have you seen this article ? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/cicd/continuous-integration-delivery

Comment: Hi @Thomas, Yes, I did and run into the error `Configured repository, but failed to import resource from workspace, this could happen if there are invalid resources.` updated OP with screenshot.

Comment: Hi paone, could you share some more details of your issue in `azure devops pipeline` scenario?

Comment: Hi @CeenoQi-MSFT, I have a new synapse workspace and trying to configure Git repository the workspace has a couple of pipelines few linked services and datasets and using a self hosted integration run time. When I try to configure Azure DevOps Git run into the error `failed to import resource from workspace` and how do I find invalid resources?

Comment: @paone I suppose that you could follow this doc [Source control in Synapse Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/cicd/source-control) to establish the integration. And also you need to check your role assignments in access control for the workspace.

Comment: @paone, any update? did the reference doc I shared help?

Comment: Hi @CeenoQi-MSFT, Yes, I had to redo from scratch and works fine now. But, When I import the repository from DEV to TEST I want DEV code to be independent of TEST and not commit my changes back to the repository. After I import the repository to TEST I had to change SQL database connection string in the source from DEV to TEST I have to commit the changes and the triggers I have setup for the pipelines don't run in TEST and fail in DEV because of the changes I did in TEST. How do I make all the environments independent once I import repository?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that you could follow this doc [Source control in Synapse Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/cicd/source-control) to establish the integration. And also you need to check your role assignments in access control for the workspace.